# using timestamp sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

trying to add a row with timestamp for my table which consists of

`time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL`

I'm using the function `now()`, but I keep getting

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2016-12-09 14:32:14.111332"`

I tried `now()::timestamp` didn't help either any idea?

```
CREATE TABLE game (
   score integer,
   score2 integer,
  time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CHECK ((score is NULL) and (score is NULL)) 
);
```

`insert into game values(2,3,now());`
Thanks!

Comment: Use *single* quotes for (text) literals " `'2016-12-09 14:32:14.111332'`

Comment: so i can't use the now function?

Comment: that didn't help either

Comment: `invalid input syntax for integer` What is the integer here ?

Comment: post the create table sql

Comment: That's what I don't understand, I have the timestamp as the input.

Comment: please post table definition and command you use for insert - looks like some wrongly placed value in insert command or something like this

Comment: Try `insert into game (score, score2, time) values(2,3,now());` Unrelated, but: `time` is a **horrible** name for a column - even worse for a `timestamp` column.

Comment: no.. same error, complainging about the time

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem resides on the CHECK...

I tested your query with few tweaks and it worked.

Working script:

```
CREATE TABLE game (
  score integer,
  score2 integer,
  time2 timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CHECK ((score is NOT NULL) and (score2 is NOT NULL)) 
);
```

[Check working example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/92d3af/2)

P.s As user @Raul mentioned, be careful with variable names to not use reserved words, time may get you into trouble

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that `2016-12-09 14:32:14.111332` is not recognized as an ISO standard.

ISO 8601 uses the 24-hour clock system. The basic format is [hh][mm][ss] and the extended format is [hh]:[mm]:[ss].
Accepted would be: `hh:mm:ss.sss`, `hh:mm:ss` or `hh:mm`.

What bothers me is all those numbers at the end: `2016-12-09 14:32:14.111332` 14.111332, I don't recall seeing timestamps like this, I might be wrong.

Maybe try inserting `2016-12-09 14:32:14` and see if it throws the same error. Also the name of the column should be changed, column with names the same as some keywords can cause statements to fail.

Comment: It's not it. I think i figured it out.. Might be some problem with a function i wrote..

Comment: Cool, maybe post the answer also, if you find it. Would be helpful for others that have the same problem.

Comment: Also as an advice, be more careful when naming columns, you might have some trouble inserting in a column with the name `date`, I think `time` is also in the same spot.